# How to center 3 boxes with gaps in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center 3 boxes, with abit of space (gutter?) between them and also space from corner of page.
I tried class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1" (col-sm-2 to make them smaller, and offset 1 for the gap), but its not really centered to the middle of the page, and also on mobile each col is "streched" to the corners and i dont want that. 
any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried in a demo.

Comment: sure,
http://www.bootply.com/eHNF5Z2XW8

Comment: How about [this](http://www.bootply.com/jnThn4pTVs)

Comment: hi Dura, thanks alot, but it still doesnt solve the problem. its not really centered, as in the right box is much closer to the right side of the screen than the left side box is from the left.. when i think about it now, it seems impossible with the grid system, because there are 12 units, and i need either 2 or 4 gaps units, then i'm left with either 8 or 10, and they dont divide by 3 :)

Comment: Not sure I follow you: col-md-4 divides the 12 unit system into 3, which I thought was what you want. Check my [updated demo](http://www.bootply.com/TxLmVjSn87)

Comment: Hi Dura, thanks again!
sorry i'm abit hard to follow since its hard for me to explain what i want.
however, with your answer, the gaps between the boxes are too small for my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your content in a `.well`. Then the padding of the columns will be your gutters. Also, you cannot use `.col-sm-3` if you want 3 columns to be centered.. you would have to use `.col-sm-2` or `.col-sm-4`

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="well">
    <h3>Column 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
  </div>        
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/CUbF8SQg8q

Comment: thanks! i didnt know about the "well"!
when  i do sm-4 its too big for my wishes (but i can deal with it, its still good), but with sm-2 i cant get it in the middle of the page. what a n00b :(

Comment: @user2105849 to use `.col-sm-2` you would need to use `col-sm-offset-3` on the first column. Here is an new example http://www.bootply.com/ejDSNv2DWX

Comment: ohh right, i should have thought about the offset by myself since I AM ALREADY USING IT, what a n00b!
anyways, thanks alot! turns out sm-2 is a bit small, so i'll stick with the 4, which looks great!
thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You need `text-center`

```css
.grid3 >div{
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-clip: content-box
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row text-center grid3">
  <div class="col-xs-3">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! while at first i thought its working PERFECTLY, turns out it ruins my jumbotron, makes it like 1/3 of the screen or something.

Comment: Also, it is not a good idea to apply a background-color directly to a column div, as this will fill the gutters with color, which will then cause other content on the page to no align correctly.

Comment: @user2105849 just change `div:not(.row)` to something different like ie: `.grid3 >div` then add that class on the `row` element.

Comment: @Schmalzy that was just the illustration see the update.